# Is it correct to say "No conozco a un chico que 'estudie' español" or shouldn't it be 'estudia'?

Tags: subjuntivo

My teacher showed my class a sentence and asked us to conjugate the verb correctly:

> No conozco a un chico que [estudiar] español.

I thought that the verb should be conjugated in the indicative (`estudia`) because it is a fact that 'I do not know such a child.'

However, my teacher insists that it should be in the subjunctive: `estudie`. She is the teacher, so I assume she is right, but could anyone please explain why?

Comment: See point 4 here http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1132/2762

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct sentence is:

> No conozco a un chico que estudie español.

This is because you use the negation (No conozco)

***Note***: People usually say:

> No conozco a ningún chico que estudie español.

If you want to use the affirmative you need to use the indicative:

> Conozco un chico que estudia español.

Why:

> Usamos el subjuntivo en clausulas subordinadas también cuando la
>   clausula principal expresa una duda. Las dudas expresan ambigüedad y
>   por eso, no podemos usar el indicativo. La negación también requiere
>   el subjuntivo en la clausula subordinada.

Example:

1. - Dudo que Camilo padezca de artritis.
   - *I doubt that Camilo suffers from arthritis.*
2. - No creo que el médico sepa el diagnóstico.
   - *I don’t believe that the doctor knows the diagnosis.*

> Los verbos de percepción física o mental en oraciones afirmativas usan
>   indicativo; en las negativas, indicativo o subjuntivo. En oraciones
>   negativas, el indicativo hace referencia al compromiso del hablante
>   con la verdad de la oración subordinada, mientras que con el
>   subjuntivo no hay este compromiso.
>
> Entre estos verbos introductores
>   están: averiguar, comprobar, criticar, darse cuenta de, entender,
>   escuchar, fijarse en, garantizar, informar de, mirar, notar, oír,
>   percibir, prever, recordar, saber, sentir, soñar, suponer, ver,
>   verificar.

Reference:

[El subjuntivo para las dudas y la negación](http://www.olemiss.edu/spanish/campiglio/downloads/p_336-342.ppsx)

[Reglas de español](http://wmx.worldmatrix.de/media/download_gallery/el_subjuntivo.pdf)

Comment: I am a little confused. If the original sentence had been "No conozco *al** chico que [estudiar] español", then **estudia** would have been correct, though it is a negative sentence

Comment: @user13560 He adicionado información nueva a la respuesta y otra referencia, puede leerla y encontrar varios ejemplos en ella.

Comment: The final "l" in the word "al" is key to the whole meaning of the sentence.  This clarifies that you are speaking of one person in particular, and now the subrodinate clause serves to identify which person, namely the one that studies Spanish.  Indicative is right in this case.

Comment: The other answers were dealing with a slightly different case.  More like "I don't know any person that studies Spanish".  In this case, the "that studies Spanish" defines a set of people, a set that could be empty in the current context.  For that reason, the rules about negatives and subjunctive apply, and those answers are correct for the case they address.

Answer (score 2):

It's "estudie". 100% sure. You can also say "esté estudiando".

You can always take a look at the DPD. Entry for "que":

> 2.1. Introduce oraciones subordinadas sustantivas en función de sujeto: «No le gusta que su mujer **trabaje**» (Hoy [Chile] 11-17.7.84);
>   de complemento directo: «¡Yo no quiero que **te vayas**!» (Santiago Sueño
>   [P. Rico 1996]); y de término de preposición, en secuencias que
>   funcionan como complemento de un sustantivo o de un adjetivo, o como
>   complemento de régimen de un verbo: «Despertó su temor el hecho de que
>   la tía Julia **fuera** boliviana» (VLlosa Tía [Perú 1977]); «Estoy segura
>   de que lo lograrás» (O’Donnell Vincent [Arg. 1982]); «Gregorio
>   insistió en que no necesitaba absolutamente nada» (Padilla Jardín
>   [Cuba 1981]).

http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the cited entry doesn't actually explain why subjunctive is needed instead of the indicative. Note that if you switch to the affirmative, you use indicative: *Conozco a un chico que estudia español*

Comment: I know, it was just an example. It actually explains the kind of phrases that can go after "que". Some of them use subjuntive.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers, but there is an additional subtlety that is worth illustrating, with this sentence:

- No conozco a un chico que estudia español.

This sentence means that there is some *specific* boy that you don't know (haven't met), who studies Spanish.  And the *a* in *no conozco a un chico* is strongly required if not obligatory in that case—it's called the "specific indefinite" in linguistics if memory serves me right.  And that sentence uses indicative because it's not hypothetical at all.